# FFMPEG is not converting video in MP4

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

FFMPEG is converting the video to MP4 format using below; however, I am not able to play the converted video.
**NOTE** : I tried with AVI format and it is playing perfecting fine but MP4 video doesn't work properly.

> "ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HP HD Camera" -t 60 -rtbufsize 100M 
>   stream.mp4"

I get below error on command line.

> real-time buffer [HP HD Camera] [video input] too full or near too
>   full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!

Comment: The quotes are for a shell;  they should not be in a ProcessBuilder argument.  Meaning:  `"video=HP HD Camera"`.  Also, you probably meant `"-t", "60"` (notice the hyphen) rather than `"t", "60"`.

Comment: Option placement matters. `-rtbufsize` is an **input** option (before `-i`), but you're applying it to the output.

Comment: Issue 2 is resolved now. Can someone guide on Issue 1?>

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M -f dshow -i video="HP HD Camera" -t 60 stream.mp4` as mentioned in my previous comment.